# Get distinct list of choices from a multiple choice field's data?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DataTable that contains a multi-select choice field (string). Values in the field are stored like:

```
Charlie
Alpha
Alpha; Charlie; Delta
Bravo; Charlie
Bravo
Alpha; Bravo; Charlie
```

I'm trying to get the unique list to display in a dropdown:

```
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
Delta
```

Method to split the values and return a `List<string>`:

```
private static List<string> GetValues(string multiValueString)
{
    string[] delimiters = {"; "};
    string[] values = multiValueString.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return values.ToList<string>();
}
```

I was trying to use LINQ to get the unique values... but can't quite figure it out. I thought I could use `dataTable.AsEnumerable()`, do a select like `.Select(r => GetValues(r.Field<string>("Brand")))` and then `Union` the results somehow.

But I can't quite get it working.. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) as `GetValues` will return mulitple items (i.e. an `IEnumerable`) for each row.  `SelectMany` flattens these enumerables into a single enumerable of the resultant type:

```
rows.SelectMany(r => GetValues(r.Field<string>("Brand")))
    .Distinct();
```

The distinct removes the duplicate entries.

Comment: Arggg yes! SelectMany is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx).

```
// values is IEnumerable<string> (say the return value from GetValues)
var uniqueValues = values.Distinct();

rows.SelectMany(r => GetValues(r.Field<string>("Brand"))).Distinct();
```

Comment: Yes, but I want the distinct values across all of the rows.. not distinct lists of values.

Comment: @Kit Menke: You can call `Distinct` on an enumeration of the flattening of the projection of each row. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Paul beat you by seconds but +1 for the help.